# iOS app can't connect to server after restarting

Tags: ios, meteor

I have disabled Hot Code Push with `solderzzc:disable-hot-code-push`
I have set up my AWS EC2 with `mup`
when I create a 
`meteor build` with `--server=IP:PORT` -flag 
or try it with 
`meteor run ios-device --mobile-server=IP:PORT` -flag

My app is working like expected on first run and is connected with the AWS EC2 server. It works also fine with TestFlight and so on BUT when I close (not in the background. a "real" app shutdown) the app and do a second coldstart my app cant connect to the server anymore. It looks like its changing the servers IPs so my app cant connect anymore.

Any ideas how to fix this?

My mup env settings:

```
"env": {
    "ROOT_URL": "http://54.218.x.x",
    "MOBILE_ROOT_URL": "http://54.218.x.x",
    "PORT": 3000
},
```

Comment: I used the xcode profiler to see where it is connecting after the 2nd coldstart. its port 80 but the same IP. It looks like the port is resetted to a default value but I have no idea to avoid port 80 and use my 3000 instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a similar problem like you. My mobile App worked fine when newly installed but lost connect to the server after an HCP took place. I solved that by adding ports to the URLs.

There are two more URLs I've collected, without knowing the difference and which one is functioning actually:

```
"env": {
    "ROOT_URL": "http://54.218.x.x:3000",
    "MOBILE_ROOT_URL": "http://54.218.x.x:3000",
    "MOBILE_DDP_URL": "http://54.218.x.x:3000",
    "DDP_DEFAULT_CONNECTION_URL": "http://54.218.x.x:3000",
    "PORT": 3000
}
```

Hope this will help